# UFD with no efficient GCD algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, computational-complexity, unique-factorization-domains, computational-number-theory

Is there a unique factorization domain where computing the GCD of two elements is thought to be computationally intractable?

Here are some relevant results I've found:

- [Wikström 2005](http://www.csc.kth.se/%7Edog/research/papers/Wik05aConf.pdf) - For all rings of integers of number fields that are principal ideal domains$^1$:

> [The algorithm] computes the greatest common divisor of its inputs in
> time $O(n^2)$ in the bit-size n of its input using naive arithmetic in $\mathbb{Z}$

- [Phatak et al. 2014](https://orbilu.uni.lu/bitstream/10993/25428/1/DoubleMod%20and%20SingleMod.pdf) - The authors attempt to construct a cryptosystem based on the existence of such a UFD. They remark (specifically for norm-Euclidean algorithms in rings of integers of quadratic fields, but the general point is similar):

> As cryptologists, we now face several puzzles:
>
> 1. That the norm-Euclidean GCD algorithm fails to exist might not rule out the existence
>    of some other kind of efficient GCD algorithm. Indeed, Kaltofen and Rolletschek [33]
>    construct a GCD algorithm in any quadratic number field (even ones with non-unique
>    factorization), with running time bounded by a polynomial function of the number
>    of bits describing the field-elements, provided D is fixed. But their running time
>    grows proportionally to a power of D, i.e., exponentially in the number of bits in D. [...]
> 2. It might be that only some quadratic fields yield security—in which case we want
>    to know which ones, how common they are, how to find them quickly, and how to
>    estimate their security levels.

1: The relevant Wikipedia page claims that the result applies to arbitrary UFDs, but this seems to be unfounded.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1993666/examples-of-a-ufds-without-factoring-algorithms?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde! However, I'm not sure I can see how this gets us closer to an example of a UFD with the properties mentioned, since we can determine coprimality without factoring (as we do in $\mathbb{Z}$). Or is there a link I'm not seeing?

Comment: I did not yet look for posts here about your question. But it is possible that they are such examples, like for the other problem I have linked. Can you give a bit more context why you would like to find such an example?

Comment: There isn't that much context to give, really - I was trying to find out about generalizations of number theoretic concepts like divisibility for various algebraic structures, and this seemed like an interesting question for whih I couldn't find an answer. That said, maybe it might be interesting in a cryptography setting - if prime factorization is hard and this also turns out to be hard, you might be able to make use of that.